# How to Extend Zend View Properly

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

In the view and layout scripts of my MVC application I regularly require access to convenience methods such as `isLoggedIn()` or `isAdmin()`.  I would like to put these in a base view so that I can access them with `$this->isLoggedIn()` or `$this->isAdmin()`.  What's the right way to do this?

I tried extending Zend_View with MY_Base_View.  I then created a View resource and initialised it from my bootstrap.  I know that its being initialised because the page title works fine.  Here's the code from the resource:

```
$this->_view = new MY_Base_View();
$this->_view->headTitle('My page title!');
```

When I'm in the view script, however, if I `print_r($this)`, it says the object is a Zend View object, (not MY_Base_View).

Have had similar problems with the layout to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh!!  Sorted it out.  In the view resource, I needed to set the view for the ViewRenderer, as follows:

```
    $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker
        ::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');
    $viewRenderer->setView($this->_view);
```

(It's in the Resources section of the manual!)  Anyhow, that's all I had to do.  In order to do its work, the layout looks for the view registered with the renderer...

Comment: You could also achieve this out of the box using view helpers